# Honda automatic trans fluid level

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, odyssey, transmission-fluid

I have an 02 Honda Odyssey. I did a trans fluid change and fill a bunch of times. I checked the level when the trans was off but did not know to   check the level when the trans is hot, so overfilled it by a half a quart. This caused the trans to shoot fluid out of the vent on three separate occasions. Twice this caused transmission failure. The third time I caught it after I caught the burning smell. My trans has an aftermarket cooler which didn't stop the problem. Why are honda transmissions touchy where they could fail if a half a quart over full?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a problem with Honda transmissions ... this could happen to *any* automatic transmission, regardless of make. Overfilling a transmission is probably #2 on the big list of no-nos with automatic transmissions, as it causes issues as you've described. The #1 issue is overheating. It is highly recommended you do not overfill any automatic transmission, I'll just leave it at that.

There is a big problem with Honda Odyssey transmissions of around your year in the first place, that being they aren't actually Odyssey transmissions, but rather the same transmission found in the Accord. It's a lot more weight to be hefting around, which causes excess wear and premature failure of the transmission when compared to the ones used in the sedans.